# QueueUserWorkItem with WaitCallback getting the return value

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, queueuserworkitem

I'm running a site that imports product feeds from a variety of shops.
These feeds can be quite huge, some are up to 1GB.
Currently I import these by calling the import function in a loop:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dtAllFeeds.Rows.Count - 1

    iImported = ImportFeed(dtAllFeeds(i).id)
    totalProductsImported += iImported
    lblStatus.Text += "FeedId: " + dtAllFeeds(i).id.ToString + "Items Imported: " + iImported.ToString

    If iImported = 0 Then
        MailFunctions.NotifyAdmin("feed error: dtAllFeeds(i).id.ToString)
    End If
Next i

lblStatus.Text += "Total imported: " + totalProductsImported.ToString
```

This works, but as the size or number of feeds increase, so does the time to process them.
So I not so elegantly just increased the timeout:

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    _timeOut = Server.ScriptTimeout
    Server.ScriptTimeout = 36000 '10 hours
End Sub
```

Now, I want to run these tasks without having to wait for each task to complete before starting the next, so I tried the setup as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671634/c-sharp-execute-method-with-parameters-with-threadpool), first with a test function `TestMultiThread`:

```
Protected Function TestMultiThread(ByVal Id As Integer, ByVal s As String) As Integer
    LogError("s = " + s)
    For i As Integer = 0 To (Id * 10000)
    Next i
    LogError(Id.ToString + " completed")
    Return Id * 10000
End Function

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
Dim numThreads = 20
Dim toProcess = numThreads
Dim resetEvent = New ManualResetEvent(False)
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To numThreads
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(Sub(state As Object)
                                                      TestMultiThread(i, toProcess.ToString)
                                                      If Interlocked.Decrement(toProcess) = 0 Then
                                                          resetEvent.[Set]()
                                                      End If
                                                  End Sub), Nothing)
Next i

resetEvent.WaitOne()
End Sub
```

I then get these errors logged:

```
s = 20
s = 20
s = 20
21 completed
21 completed
21 completed
s = 19
s = 18
s = 17
21 completed
21 completed
s = 16
21 completed
s = 15
21 completed
s = 14
21 completed
s = 13
21 completed
s = 12
21 completed
s = 11
21 completed
s = 10
21 completed
s = 9
21 completed
s = 8
21 completed
s = 7
21 completed
s = 6
21 completed
s = 5
21 completed
s = 4
21 completed
s = 3
21 completed
21 completed
```

I don't understand this order of logging, howcome I don't see `s = <value>` for 20 unique values (but `s=20` even 3 times in a row in the beginning and missing `s=2` and `s=1`? And why is `i` always 21 in function `TestMultiThread`?

Comment: It's called "capturing the loop var", see answer below and [here (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43979917/).

Comment: But the real question here should have been  "how to process feeds in parallel", the good answers would not have involved QueueUserWorkItem.

Comment: @Henk I did touch on a more appropriate way to handle the situation after explaining why the QUWI usage was giving unexpected results.

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems. First of all, I can't even compile it with `For i = 0 To (i * 10000)` in `TestMultiThread`, because you are also using `i` as the parameter name.

Second of all, the strangeness you're seeing is because you're passing the loop iterator `i` to `TestMultiThread`, which is a modified closure--you're capturing the variable itself rather than its value. By the time each thread pool delegate runs, the value of `i` is 21, having been incremented after each iteration of the loop body. To solve this problem, copy `i` to a local variable within the loop body and instead pass that local variable to `TestMultiThread`.

Finally, since this is being done in the context of ASP.NET, be aware that spinning up a bunch of new threads will rob the ASP.NET thread pool of threads it can use to handle incoming requests. [Stephen Cleary explains](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html):

> - The request starts processing on an ASP.NET thread.
> - `Task.Run` starts a task on the thread pool to do the calculations. The ASP.NET thread
>     pool has to deal with (unexpectedly) losing one of its threads for
>     the duration of this request.
> - The original request thread is returned 
>     to the ASP.NET thread pool.
> - When the calculation is complete, that
>     thread completes the request and is returned to the ASP.NET thread
>     pool. The ASP.NET thread pool has to deal with (unexpectedly) getting 
>     another thread.

`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` in your case is analagous to `Task.Run` in his example--it creates a background thread. If you want to do fire-and-forget in ASP.NET, look into using [`HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn636893.aspx), [as Cleary suggests](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html). If you actually need to do anything with the feeds after you've imported them, then consider taking advantage of [asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/async) to start each import before awaiting them all concurrently (I assume you are calling APIs--a naturally asynchronous operation--since you are importing the feeds "from a variety of shops").

Comment: Thank you. It looks like the `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` is the quickest win. Not sure what you mean by `If you actually need to do anything with the feeds after you've imported them`, I ONLY need the return value (number of items imported) from the function that imports a feed...is `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` still my best bet or should I look into async programming? Thanks again.

Comment: I was trying to distinguish between "fire-and-forget"-style background work and normal work that you're just trying to parallelize. It sounds like you should create a task for importing the feed from each shop and then `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)`.